# indirect with same table on different coordinates on other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I just wonder if it's possible to automatize indirect function when the same table is in a different cell range, for example, "C4:D10" in one case and   "C5:D11" on another sheet.   we want to get some data from those tables on the same sheet with an indirect function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `INDIRECT()`? Why not `OFFSET()`?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.

An example of what you might do would be to create a Table/range in which you had a column for a quick, but meaningful name for each sheet's data range. (The more in the name, the better, for clarity, but if typing into an entry cell to switch sheets' tables, the more tiresome that would get. However... with a dropdown attached/enabled for the entry cell, that becomes mostly a non-issue.)

Then you'd have a column with the formula `=A1:K43` (using whatever address encompasses the table at this moment. Those formulas would generate the `#SPILL!` error, but that is of utterly no concern. You only want them to exist to pull information from the formula, formulas which Excel will take care of adjusting as you adjust your tables' borders. Interestingly, unlike so many errors Excel presents, the `#SPILL!` error does not halt any further use of the information in the cell so `FORMULATEXT()`, for example, can read the formula inside the cell AND Excel can do the auto-adjusting for most things you do that affect the range's reference.

Then last column needed would be a `FORMULATEXT()` to get the up-to-date formula and therefore reference that will address the data range, wrapped by a `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove the initial `=` from it.

You would access each sheet's reference by having an entry cell in which you type the name you gave each table. If using a dropdown for that cell, you'd just select the name from the list. Then, where you want the upper left corner of the resulting table, you use a lookup formula of choice (almost), perhaps `VLOOKUP()`, to find the value in the third column of the lookup table. (*Not `XLOOKUP()` though... it chokes on the idea.*)

Wrap `INDIRECT()` around that and you are good to go. Something like the following:

```
=INDIRECT(  VLOOKUP(  E1,  A1:C1098,  3,  FALSE)  )
```

(If your lookup cell were E1 and you had 1098 of these tables in your lookup range of A1:C1098. Adjust as seems a good idea...)

You can get fancier, but that lays out the basic idea. Examples of "fancier" might be using Named Ranges for each data table keep a list of just them somewhere for your dropdown to draw from. I'd do that, and I'd keep that list in another Named Range. Then no looking up is needed on your part as the dropdown would do the looking up for you. If doing the lookups, you could place the `FORMULATEXT()` part of things IN the lookup formula itself so you only need a two column lookup table. Stuff like that. Personally, I like to walk before I run unless the "running" part is clear and easy, then improve the spreadsheet every time I open it. Or in a shared environment, every couple months perhaps for things that happen under the hood. Things users are aware of? Depends STRONGLY on company culture.

I would not suggest going the `OFFSET()` route as that seems fraught with pitfalls. You could coax it into a dynamic form which you'd surely want since each range could be all over the place, but... it would not be as intuitive. Nothing wrong with it, just this is easier for the situation you described.

Also, so long as "volatile" using `INDIRECT()` is roughly the same as "volatile" using `OFFET()` performance-wise, there's nothing to give either an edge in that respect. Not that "volatile" is of any significance to modern (say, anything running Windows 10) computers until you get to something on the scale of 50,000-100,000 rows and 20-30 columns, and even then my December 2015 box blinks just a second for the 100,000 by 30 example. A second, literally, not an imprecise use of the word. But your use may involve mobile devices, Chromebooks, older computers, etc., and it might matter to you that in this case, one or the other doesn't really make make a difference.